# Apexcharts does not work with style visibility display = ‘none’

Tags: javascript, html, css, visibility, apexcharts

I have a simple web application using plain html/css/js (no framework). I have implemented a tabbed pane where the implementation is based on css turning visibility.display on/off.
In one of the panes I have a few Apexcharts, and in the other panes there are no charts.
If I have the pane with the charts visible at startup everything works fine, but if the pane with the charts is hidden initially, the charts does not show up when that pane becomes visible. The rest of the html on the charts pane becomes visible correctly.

It looks like the DOM context of the charts must be visible when the DOM objects of the charts are created.

Is this the expected behavior or is it a bug? Is there some “work around”?

The behaviour is pretty clear and an example may help, but I am not sure it would in this case.

In case you want to explore the phenomena it is just making sure that the element that contains the chart is not visible when you render the chart initially.
Create an element and set it to style.display=’none’. Add a chart to the element and render the chart. Now you make the element visible by setting style.display=’block’. The chart is not shown even if the element itself becomes visible. If you call render() on the chart it will show. After this you could turn style.display ’on’/’off’ any number of times and the chart becomes visible every time it is turned ’on’.
So it seems that the first call to render() becomes a no-op in case it is called while the chart is in a non-visible element.

A guess could be that Apexcharts checks the visibility state of the element during render(), and there might be valid reasons to do so, but then it ought to be documented that render() becomes a no-op under these circumstances. Or it might be so that Apexcharts should not care about the visibility state and let the DOM environment care about that, but then you need to more about the Apexcharts internals.

Comment: Are you able to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? That would make understanding the issue/bug easier.